What is the cleaning and disinfection protocol for moving into an apartment previously occupied by a dog of unknown medical history?
I'm unsure whether my question is on-topic for this SE, but since it relates to dogs, I decided to give it a try.
A friend of mine recently bought an apartment where the previous owner lived with a dog. My friend wants to move in but is concerned about the potential risk of contracting a parasitic worm, fungal, or bacterial infection due to the dog's prior residence. While she understands that the risks may not be very high, she wants to eliminate them entirely.
My question: Is there an established protocol for cleaning and disinfecting an apartment to eliminate any health risks associated with a dog of unknown medical history having previously lived there?
We've tried researching this online but have only found general advice like "clean thoroughly," rather than detailed protocols that guarantee that no health risks remain and specify the cleaning agents to use.
Some additional details: The apartment is free of carpets and furniture (aside from a couple of shelves left by the previous owner) and has laminate flooring. Stray pieces of dog hair can still be found in various spots. My friend isn't allergic to dogs, so the primary concern is preventing infections of any kind. She wants to rest assured that her new apartment is totally safe to live in.

This is not a complete answer because I'm not aware of such a cleaning protocol. Honestly, I think no special cleaning is necessary unless the person moving into the apartment is deathly allergic to dogs or has a very severely compromised immune system (like after an organ transplant). "Unknown medical history" does not mean that the dog had any disease, it just means you don't know how the former owner cared for their dog. But it's safe to assume that the former owner also didn't want to get infected with anything from their dog, so they probably didn't ignore any signs of disease in their dog.
The risk of an infection with parasitic worms is close to zero. Parasites usually cannot survive outside of a hosts body for long and unless you literally lick the floors with your tongue, I cannot imagine how you could get infected.
The same applies to fleas, mites and other blood-sucking parasites. They need regular access to a host body to survive. Only ticks can survive a few weeks without a host body, but they are very obvious dark spots (usually) on the walls.
Viruses and bacteria are not much different in that most die after a few hours or days outside of a body.
Fungi are the only germs I'm aware of that can survive a longer time in the form of spores. But I lack the knowledge of how long spores of different infectious fungi can survive or how to safely kill them. As far as I know fungal infections are quite rare in domestic dogs.
Summary
In my personal opinion no special cleaning protocol is necessary. Just vacuum the floors and wipe them with regular floor cleaners.
Even old dog hair is mostly safe. Real health risks are usually found in body fluids like blood, saliva, vomit, urine and feces. If there is no such thing in the apartment, there's no reason to assume it's not safe.
If you are paranoid about germs, you can wipe the floors with antimicrobial cleaners (like those used in healthcare facilities) or a bleach solution. Please follow the safety instructions (like opening the windows and not mixing different cleaning products), otherwise your fear of germs might cause you more bodily harm than any dirt in the apartment.
